# Smoothing of Implied Volatilty

Tags: implied-volatility, modeling

I'm using ATM 30D implied volatility in a model I'm building, but need to smooth out the data. Is the best way just to use exponential smoothing or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: if you don't explain what you are doing there is not right or wrong answer so as it stands the question is not really meaningful.

Comment: I'm attempting to model a rate set by a third party. This entity has stated it uses different measure of market volatility to set this rate, so am using implied vol as one input. Using raw data however is a problem because there are some outliers that are causing issues with my model. General I can take care of outliers by smoothing data, but didn't know if there was another preferred method.

Comment: I agree with @Ezy: the question is still not precise enough. Where do you get this ATM implied vol from? from swaptions prices? What is the "data" you are referring to?

Comment: The implied volatility is from options on futures. The data is the implied vol data points.

Comment: Question not clear. Do you want to smooth across strikes, or historical vol data, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There does not exist a “preferred method” which works in general. Usually interpolation schemes suitedness depends on specifics of the problem at hand and the particular utility of what you are trying to do.